# Click all positions in a given region

Tags: python, click

I currently have a rectangular on the screen, which has the position of **(x,y)** from **(0,69)** to **(1918,1038)**

What I want is to **click all the points** in this region as fast as I can, and each click has 20 pixel in difference with the old one

How can I implement that, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyautogui` for the clicking part, and a simple loop for the locations.

```
import pyautogui

def clickarea(start:tuple, end:tuple, diff:int) -> None:
     #segregate x and y values
     xloc, yloc = zip(start, end)

     for x in range(*xloc, diff):
        for y in range(*yloc, diff):
            print(f'clicking {x},{y}')
            pyautogui.click(x, y)
     
clickarea((0,69), (1918,1038), 20)
```